# Limiting voltage after potentiometer

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am having trouble finding a device or circuit which will help me on my quest to control the maximum output of a circuit, with a varying voltage produced by a potentiometer.

If lets say, I have a 5v reference voltage, changed to 0.25v-4.75v by potentiometer, and I wish to limit the output voltage to 3.75v, how would I go about this? I have looked into zener diodes but they only work with dropping voltage from a higher to a lower amount. Resistors are no good due to ohms law, the voltage is variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Increase the resistor between the potentiometer's positive terminal and the supply, so it only covers the range you actually care about?

Comment: If, with 5 volts into the pot circuit, you get out 0.25 to 4.5 volts, Part 1.then it either already has a resistor network installed or mechanical stops on the wiper. 1.) Which is it?  2.) If it's a resistor network, is it internal or external?  3.) what's the value of the pot? 4.) If the voltage output limits are now 0.25 and 4.75 volts, what do you want the new limits to be?

Comment: I am not sure, it is in an automotive application and haven't removed it yet. i will assume it has stops on the wiper as it is just 5V in from the ECU and 0.25-4.75V out. I have no idea of the value of the pot,due to it being a refernce sensor in the throttle pedal the current is not very high if that helps at all. Basically i am wanting to set up a switch that can limit the output voltage of the throttle pedal

Comment: Part 2. Determine the value of the pot: If it has an external resistor network installed, measure the resistance across the whole pot.  If the resistor network is internal,  1.) measure the resistance between the CCW terminal and the wiper with the wiper full CCW 2.) Measure the resistance between the CW terminal and the wiper with the wiper full CW 3.) Measure the resistance between the CW and CCW terminals. 4.) add the resistances found in 1 and 2, subtract that sum from the resistance found in 3. and the difference will be either the pot's resistance  or the resistance between the stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, or addition to @OlinLathrops answer is to use a zener on the output of the pot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhgcHV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the switch on, the output will be limited to the zener voltage. The 100R resistor has been added to limit the current through the zener in the event the pot's mechanical limits fail on the advice of @RDrast

Comment: Doesn't the input have to be higher than the output for using a zener though? so if output from pot was 2V and zener had a voltage control to 3.75V, it wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes (sort of). You want to limit the voltage. So for voltage outputs from the pot between 0 and 3.75V the zener does nothing, try to set a higher voltage, and the zener starts to conduct, limiting the voltage to 3.75V

Comment: Ok i see. So the zener has to be set up in parallel or series?
Also the triangle, is that a NOT gate?

Comment: It has to be connected as shown in the schematic, in parallel with the output of the pot. The triangle is a GND symbol

Comment: is the triangle a NOT gate?

Comment: No its a GND - just conventional to show one side of a circuit as GND

Comment: Sorry i am a novice at electronics. I am confused because I thought that electricity flowed from negative to positive. So the zener and switch go in parallel to the pot. Doesn't electricity take the path of least resistance though, so it would ignore the pot and just travel at 3.75V constantly through the zener, until the pot reached above that and then the electricity would be more happy going that way instead?

Comment: ahaa now i understand the purpose of the GND ;) 
thanks for your help
just a thought, wouldn't all the electricity in this circuit just go to ground though, and ignore the pot and everything else?

Comment: Electrons do 'drift' from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, but 'conventional' current flow is considered to be from positive to negative. The zener can't generate any voltage. The 5V supply is divided by the resistance of the pot (split by the wiper), until the potential at the wiper reaches 3.75V above the negative terminal (GND in my diagram) the zener will not have sufficient breakdown voltage across it to allow it to conduct.

Comment: so the electricity goes through the pot until the voltage required to activate the zener is reached, at which point it goes through the zener and not the pot?
Sorry i bet i sound as daft as a brush with no bristles

Comment: Yes, but some current will continue to flow through both halves of the pot, even when the voltage is high enough to make the zener conduct. You should do some basic research into circuits, ohms law and voltage dividers.

Comment: do i have to connect the diode part of the circuit to the wiper on the pot?

Comment: Yes from the wiper to the negative side - as per the schematic - I seem to be repeating myself.

Comment: But if the pot is all the way up, the zener will have no current limiting aside from the source impedance.  Not a good thing.

Comment: @RDrast That would be true if the potentiometer output went all the way to 5V but the OP's potentiometer only goes to 4.75V - its an automotive pot, so probably has mechanical limits.

Comment: @Icy Still, that is never something to rely on.  I always have to take the worst case into account, including changing the pot out at a future date, and not using an exact replacement, or turning it past the mechanical limits.

Comment: Isn't it? What can you rely on?. A mechanical stop creates a fixed resistor - would you rely on a discrete fixed resistor?. I will add a current limiting resistor to the wiper output to my circuit, but then will we be affecting the output impedance? should I add a voltage follower to make sure this change doesn't affect anything?

Answer (score 3):

If you want 250 mV to 4.75 V out of a pot using a 5 V supply, then put resistors on either end of the pot.  That's like having a pot that can't be adjusted to the ends.

Let's say you will use a 10 kΩ pot.  That 10 kΩ will span a range of 4.5 V.  The rest is simple voltage divider math.  If 10 kΩ drops 4.5 V, then 556 Ω will drop 250 mV.  Therefore, a 10 kΩ pot with 556 Ω resistors on each end will give you the adjustment range of 250 mV to 4.75 V that you want.

Comment: Thank you. So in essence i need to modify the pot, or could i use the two resistors you mentioned in a circuit with a switch, so i can limit to 3.75v with circuit open, and 4.75v with circuit closed?

I am still wanting the pot to carry on doing its normal thing with adjusting the voltage so the output is varying, just limit the maximum voltage.

Forgot to mention, the pot already has the output values of 250mV and 4.75V

Comment: you could use a switch to short out one or both of the fixed series voltage limiting resistors, but you will get a step change in voltage at the pot output, when operating the switch.